# Find a character and the character before it in an element and wrap it with a span

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, innerhtml

I want to wrap an apostrophe that appears in h1 tags and character immediately before it. e.g. `<h1>Can't</h1>` would be like this `<h1>Ca<span>n'</span>t</h1>`

I can do the apostrophe part using the following

```js
$("h1:contains('')").html(function(_, html) {
   return html.replace(/(')/g, '<span>$1</span>');
});
```

```css
span { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Can't</h1>
```

How would I go about selecting the character before the apostrophe?

Comment: Regarding all the so far provided answers, are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1):

- Add a class to the regex: `[a-z]`
- If for some reason you need to match upper case letters as well you can as Relias mentioned add a second range of upper case letters: `/([a-zA-Z]')/g`
- Or you can use the case-<kbd>i</kbd>nsensitivity flag: `/([a-z]')/gi`

```js
$("h1:contains('')").html(function(_, html) {
   return html.replace(/([a-z]')/g, '<span>$1</span>');
});
```

```css
span { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Can't</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP mainly has two [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) pattern options to choose from ...

- [`/(?<=\p{L})'(?=\p{L})/gu`](https://regex101.com/r/GzFJOa/1) utilizes a [***lookaround***](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind) (both positive [***lookbehind***](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind) and [***lookahead***](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookahead)), where, for the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)ment, the OP does neither need a reference to the letter before nor to the letter after the single quote, not even to the single quote itself; thus the OP could just go with a [string-based replacement-pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_the_replacement) like `<span>'</span>`. For the match itself included into the string the latter would change to ... `<span>$&</span>`.

  **Note:** The above also is the correct approach for targeting any apostrophe / single quote which is supposed to be both, lead and followed by a letter, whereas the OP's code would just wrap any occurring apostrophe.
- [`/(\p{L})'(\p{L})/gu`](https://regex101.com/r/GzFJOa/2) uses two unnamed [***capturing groups***](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups), where one then needs to go for a [replacement-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement) which gets the match and the group values passed in as arguments ... with the function then looking like this ... `` (match, before, after) => `<span>${ before }'</span>${ after }` `` ... ***in order to fulfill the OP's requirement of the additionally highlighted leading letter***.

  **Note:** The second approach of cause also would serve the case of the solely highlighted apostrophe ... `` (match, before, after) => `${ before }<span>'</span>${ after }` ``.

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('h1')
  .forEach(elmNode =>
    elmNode.innerHTML =
      // with a positive lookaround (both positive lookbehind and lookahead).
      //
      // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/GzFJOa/1]
      elmNode.innerHTML.replace(/(?<=\p{L})'(?=\p{L})/gu, '<span>$&</span>')
  );

document
  .querySelectorAll('p')
  .forEach(elmNode =>
    elmNode.innerHTML =
      elmNode.innerHTML.replace(
        // without any lookaround but with two unnamed capturing groups,
        // here referred to as the function arguments `before` and `after`.
        //
        // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/GzFJOa/2]
        /(\p{L})'(\p{L})/gu,
        (match, before, after) => `<span>${ before }'</span>${ after }`

      //(match, before, after) => `${ before }<span>'</span>${ after }`
      // solely highlighted apostrophe/single quote
      )
  );
```

```css
h1, p { font-size: 1.2em; margin: 0; padding: 0 3px; }
h1 span { color: red; }
p span { color: orange; font-weight: bolder; }
```

```html
<h1><em>Can't</em></h1>
<h1>don't <em>I'm</em></h1>
<h1>doesn't<br/>'enclosed by single quotes'</h1>

<p><em>Can't</em></p>
<p>don't <em>I'm</em></p>
<p>doesn't<br/>'enclosed by single quotes'</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use a *[character class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards)*, and include the range of characters.

The syntax is *[ ]*, and a range will be, in this case *a-z*.
Additionally, to match uppercase letters, add an additional range, *A-Z*

```
[a-zA-Z]'
```

```js
$("h1:contains('')").html(function(_, html) {
   return html.replace(/([a-zA-Z]')/g, '<span>$1</span>');
});
```

```css
span { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Can't</h1>
```